# Solrj query two date exception

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I use `Apache Solr 4` and I new at `Solr`, I want to add `last_modified` by `date chooser`, but I get exception when I add some document which have own `last_modified`. This exception I get.
    org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request

I add field `shema.xml`  `las_date`, but now i can't query range two date like this 
**attr_las_date:[2013-01-00T20:00:00Z TO 2013-01-10T19:59:59Z]**
, because in `schema.xml` *attr_** format is `String`

```
public static void indexFilesSolrCell(String fileName, String solrId,String fileAuthor, String fileDate,String fileDescription, String fileTitle) 
    throws IOException, SolrServerException {

    String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr"; 
    SolrServer solr = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(urlString);

    ContentStreamUpdateRequest up 
      = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract"); 
    up.addFile(new File(fileName));
    up.setParam("literal.id", solrId.replaceAll("\\s","").replaceAll("\\(","").replaceAll("\\)", ""));
    up.setParam("literal.url", fileName);
    up.setParam("literal.name", solrId);
    up.setParam("literal.content_type",solrId);
    up.setParam("uprefix", "attr_");
    up.setParam("fmap.content", "content");
    up.setParam("literal.owner",fileAuthor);    
    up.setParam("literal.last_modified", fileDate);
    up.setParam("literal.description", fileDescription);
    up.setParam("literal.title", fileTitle);
    up.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);


    solr.request(up);

    QueryResponse rsp = solr.query(new SolrQuery("*:*"));
}
```

How I add the date to documents?

Comment: i know , i added this field <field name="las_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/> , but when i range between two years it work true, but when i  range two days i don't get anything

Answer (score 0):

There should be

```
<field name="las_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
```

in your schema.xml